# Does there exist a "nice" class of integer matrix that every integer matrix is similar to?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

This is a soft question. I was wondering if there are any known classes $C$ of integer matrices such that every $M \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is similar (via an integral matrix) to an element in $C$?

I am hoping that $C$ would be a set of matrices with many $0$s. In general, we know that $M$ is not similar to an upper triangular matrix or its Smith Normal Form. Unfortunately, I can't find any relevant results about this.

Any reference would be really appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps there are useful facts in the references to the [conjugacy problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77133/conjugacy-in-gln-mathbb-z) for $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$.